# Angular: HttpGet request leads to HttpErrorResponse

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-httpclient

I am creating a Web Application with Angular and I want to send a HttpRequest using get to receive data from my api server.

This is my data client for http get:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getData(url: string): Observable<any> {
    console.log("getting data from API with url: " + url);
    return this.http.get(url, { responseType: 'json' });
  }
}
```

And I call it through button click using:

```
this.dataService.getData(requestString).subscribe(
      (data: any) => {
        console.log(data);
      });
```

When I try it it get the error message:

```
ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: 'Unknown Error', url: '...', ok: false, …}
```

If I try the exact same url via postman it works and I get my result.
Is there anything I am missing or that is wrong?

Comment: What is the o/p of console.log inside getData service? This could be a cors error. Post your full error details

Comment: There is not output, thats the problem, the request crashes before that can happen.

Comment: What happens if you hard-code the URL in getData service instead of passing by reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Actually I had 2 different problems:

1. My launch.json was wrong. Since I launched on chrome I needed "--disable-web-security" runtime argument:

```
     {
              "type": "chrome",
              "request": "launch",
              "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
              "url": "http://localhost:4200",
              "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
              "runtimeArgs": [
                "--disable-web-security"
              ]
        }
```

2. Since my api usually takes a long time (~3min) to answer I also needed to add a longer timeout to the request:

```
    this.http.get(url, { responseType: 'json', headers: new HttpHeaders({ timeout: '300000' }) })
```